# Java UDP send - receive packet one by one

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to send and receive some Audio encoded data via UDP, and confused.

First of all, I have done UDP send-receive before on C# and node.js, and receiving the packet one by one is very straight forward and easy, but it's different in Java, and confusing me.

The every encoded data size is approximately  `360-380 bytes` for each,

and I need to send this **encoded data as a packet** to remote(or *localhost* so far) via UDP.

The UDP-receiver should receive **the encoded data as a packet** and process to decode.

Here is a brief example to illustrate what I do.

**Encoder and UDP-sender**

```
  ds = new DatagramSocket(localPort);
  //a Thread with While loop----------
  Log.d("AudioEncoder", outData.length + " bytes encoded");
  //The encoded data size is about 370 bytes for each

  packet = new DatagramPacket(outData, outData.length,
  InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), localPort);
  ds.send(packet);
```

**UDP-receiver and Decoder**

```
ds = new DatagramSocket(localPort);
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, buffer2.length);

while (isPlaying)
{
        ds.receive(packet); 
        Log.d("UDP-receiver",  buffer2.length + " bytes received");

        //do Decoding on buffer2
        //..........
}
```

Basically, a packet (encoded byte data) size to send and receive is approximately 360-380 bytes for each.

Then, I understand for Java `Datagram`, make a buffer for a specific byte size such as `512 or 1024` (I don't know what size is most optimized in this case, and in these days).

If I set the `DatagramPacket` size `1024 bytes`, the packet which size is `360-380 bytes` comes twice to be pooled in the buffer, then the original 2 packets are joind together then processed as a single byte array?

If I set the `DatagramPacket` size `512 bytes`, the packet which size is `360-380 bytes` comes twice to be pooled in the buffer, then since it's overflowed the buffer size, the single packet arrived is swiped to be processed?

Again, it's sufficient at least, the receiver can receive a packet one by one, then process for each, but things looks complicated here.

Please instruct me . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I set the DatagramPacket size 1024 bytes, the packet which size is 360-380 bytes comes twice to be pooled in the buffer, then the original 2 packets are joind together then processed as a single byte array?

No. You receive two separate packets.

> If I set the DatagramPacket size 512 bytes, the packet which size is 360-380 bytes comes twice to be pooled in the buffer

No.

> then since it's overflowed the buffer size, the single packet arrived is swiped to be processed?

I don't know what 'swiped' means, but none of this happens. You receive two separate packets.

Comment: Ok, thanks EJP. To me, to configure the buffer size pre-alocated does not make sense, actually C# or node does not do this so.  Then I have another question. When the receiving buffer size is set, say 1024, on receiving packet which actual size is, 350, is there way to know the exact size is.

Comment: shot another subsequent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868956/how-to-obtain-the-actual-packet-size-byte-array-in-java-udp