# How to obtain the actual packet size `byte[]` array in Java UDP

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

This is the subsequent question of my previous one:
[Java UDP send - receive packet one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866382/java-udp-send-receive-packet-one-by-one)

As I indicated there, basically, I want to receive a packet one by one as it is via UDP.

Here's an example code:

```
ds = new DatagramSocket(localPort);
byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer1, buffer1.length);

ds.receive(packet); 
Log.d("UDP-receiver",  packet.getLength() 
                             + " bytes of the actual packet received");
```

Here, the actual packet size is say, 300bytes, but the `buffer1` is allocated as 1024 byte, and to me, it's something wrong with to deal with `buffer1`.

How to obtain the actual packet size `byte[]` array from here?

and, more fundamentally, why do we need to preallocate the buffer size to receive UDP packet in Java like this? ( node.js doesn't do this )

Is there any way not to pre-allocate the buffer size and directly receive the UDP packet as it is?

Thanks for your thought.

Answer (score 6):

You've answered your own question. `packet.getLength()` returns the actual number of bytes in the received datagram. So, you just have to use `buffer[]` from index `0` to index `packet.getLength()-1.`

Note that this means that if you're calling `receive()` in a loop, you have to recreate the `DatagramPacket` each time around the loop, or reset its length to the maximum before the receive. Otherwise `getLength()` keeps shrinking to the size of the smallest datagram received so far.

Comment: Ok thanks EJP, I posted my own answer here. and it seems working properly looking at my log.

Answer (score 4):

self answer. I did as follows:

```
int len = 1024;
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[len];
DatagramPacket packet;

byte[] data;
while (isPlaying)
{
    try
    {
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, len);
        ds.receive(packet);
        data = new byte[packet.getLength()];
        System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), data, 0, packet.getLength());
        Log.d("UDPserver",  data.length + " bytes received");
    }
    catch()//...........
//...........
```

Comment: This is pointless. You already have a byte array containing the data, and you already have the length of the data, so `Log.d("UDPserver",  packet.length() + " bytes received")` would work, as does the code you already posted in your question. There is no need to allocate another array and copy data around.